# Access the protected variable from a nested class to the enclosing class

Tags: c++, object-oriented-analysis

```
class A  
{  
public:  
   class B  
   {  
      public:  
          int changevar (int b)  
          {  
            a = b; // 5 should go in "a"   
          }  
          int get()  
          {  
            return a;     
          }     
      protected:  
          int a = 0; // value initialized here  
   };

   private:
        int usechangedvar(B& hello);
};

int A::usechangedvar(B& hello)
{
    int final = hello.get(); // 5 should go in "final"    
    return final;
}

int main()
{
    A::B hi;
    hi.changevar(5);
    
    A obj;
    obj.usechangedvar(hi);
}
```

This code will not compile because it will say that I am trying to access the private method.
Regardless, I am not sure what is the correct way of doing this but finally what I want is:
Under class B there is a protected variable whose value is changed by the public method called "changevar". Once the value is changed, I need to store that value in the variable "final" inside the private method called "usechangedvar".

Note: I do not want to change the variable "a" from protected to something else.

Edit: I am open to suggestions where class B is not a nested class. I can keep it outside meaning A and B are not within one another

EDITED:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>



class A
{
   public:
   class B
   {
      public:
          int changevar (int b) ------------- This method is called by application code(user) and whatever value user gives here should be the changed value
          {
            a = b; // 5 should go in "a"
            
          }
        //   int get()
        //   {
        //     return a;   
        //   }   
        protected:
            int a = 0; // value initialized here. This could be anything private/protected
   };
   
   class C : public class B
   {
       
   };

   private:
        int usechangedvar();
};

int A::usechangedvar()
{
    // 5 should come here which was inputted by user.
}

int main()
{
    //1) I instantiate class C by doing
    A::C objC;
    objC.changevar(5);
    // Whole purpose is to take 5 from user and then use it eventually in "usechangedvar" method.
}
```

Comment: You cannot call method `usechangedvar()` from `main()` as it is private. That unrelated to any details of class `B` wether its members protected or not. So either make  `usechangedvar()` accessible or do not use it outside of class `A`.

Comment: There is no special relationship between `A` and `A::B` in C++ (you're probably coming from Java, where that isn't the case).  If these classes weren't "inside" each other, and just free `A` and `B` how would you do this?  Think that way.  You are somewhat unclear what you want right now.  You correctly access `B` via reference... but `final` (think of a different name btw) is made during the duration of the method, and then discarded.  Its lifetime is very short.  You need to express better what you *want* to do, so we can help you do it.

Comment: @Aconcagua that will not change anything

Comment: @Slava Are you saying that since method "usechangedvar" is private, I cannot do reference of class B as a parameter of that method? --usechangedvar(B& hello)
In order to solve this, I have to make this method public?

Comment: @Slava Ah, indeed, missed that `usechangedvar` isn't even using the protected member...

Comment: @Aconcagua yes I tried doing friend class but it does not work

Comment: @KevinAnderson I am new to C++ and I do not come from Java background. But my whole goal is to use the updated variable(which is a protected variable) from a nested class (B) and use it in the private method of enclosing class (A). I am open to suggestions if you have any regarding changing the structure

Comment: @varconst The problem is the function being private, as Slava already stated. It is not about not being able to use the reference, but the fact that you do not have access to the function *itself*. You might write another member of `A` demonstrating the point: `int A::demo() { B b; return useunchangedvar(b); }` – still you can pass by reference, even though the function is private...

Comment: No I am not saying that, see my answer.

Comment: @Aconcagua I just edited the question stating that I am open to suggestion to remove class B as a nested class and keep it outside completely

Comment: @varconst Your code does not show how you would want to use the protected member of `B` other than from via public getter. So either you haven't provided a [mre] (in which case you have *two* independent errors) or you are not focusing on the right aspect of the problem.

Comment: @varconst Keeping the class `B` outside of `A` won't change anything. That was just an analogy of Kevin for better understanding. The problem with the code as is is *neither* class `B` being nested *nor* accessing private/protected members from *within* `useunchangedvar`, *but* from accessibility of the latter from *outside* of `A`. For demonstration, remove the `B&` parameter from the function and try to call it from `main`. It *still* won't work.

Comment: @Aconcagua     
int final = hello.get(); -- I am using the protected member of class B called "a" in this line.     
return final;

Comment: @Aconcagua okay, so the only option is to make the method from private to public?

Comment: @varconst `get` is in the **public** section of `B`!

Comment: @varconst In general: no. Generally you can make specific functions friends as well, in given case the `main` function. Meaningful? In given case, I doubt pretty much. So then indeed only remains making the member function public. Meaningful use cases where you'd make functions friends comprise e. g. free standing `operator>>` or `operator<<` for streams.

Comment: @Aconcagua I meant make "usechangedvar" this method public. What does "get" method have to do anything with this?

Comment: @varconst `get` is the red herring (or one of several ones) driving your focus away from the actual problem; citing your own comment a few minutes ago: `int final = hello.get();`.

Comment: (I, too, wince at the use of `final` as an identifier.)

Comment: I find it way too hard to figure out what you are trying to do, lack of context contributing. Access a non-public instance data member of class B from a function of class A? What is your specific problem with that?

Comment: (When editing your question, check whether the title still fits. Put information missing from the question right there, not in another comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem reproduced with unrelated details eliminated:

```
class A  
{  
   private:
        int usechangedvar(int hello) { return hello; }
};

int main()
{
    A obj;
    obj.usechangedvar(5); //compile error, usechangedvar is private
}
```

Problem in your code is completely unrelated to class `B` as you can see here - you cannot call `A::usechangedvar()` from `main()` as it is private method of class `A`.

If you just need to check if your method `usechangedvar()` works you may add public method to A for example `test()`, call `usechangedvar()` from it and probably print the result. Then you can call `obj.test()` from `main()` and see if it works. You may want to remove that method `test()` if necessary after test is done.

Comment: So what can I do in this case? You can also think of A and B as 2 separate classes and then tell me the solution. 
My only non negotiable thing is, I cannot change the usechangedvar to public but I can keep it either private/protected.
I cannot change the variable "a" to public/private but just keep it protected

Comment: Duh. Again your problem not related to class B, you can make them separate, you can make them nested, you can make whole class B public, problem in current code is in class A and main. Solution - either not to call private method of class A from main(), make that method public, or main friend. It is not clear why you try to call private method outside of class A so I cannot say what method should be used.

Comment: inside class A, I define
"friend class main"
Like this you mean?

Comment: main() is not a class, but function. Anyway that would be strange and very unlikely to be correct solution. But again I cannot suggest as I do not know why you try to use private method from `main()`

Comment: So it's not "main()"
what I have is, in hpp file I have private method defined. In cpp file I am defining the method. Inside that method, I have to use that "final" variable. There is no "main" in my actual code. 
You can think of some other function(part of A) calling that private method.

Comment: In your case it is `int main()`

Comment: Edited the comment

Comment: @varconst How the preferrable/recommendable solution looks like does not so much depend on what you *have* already but rather on what the *purpose* of all this is. You haven't lost a word about the latter, though. Discussing based on the former easily ends up in [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Aconcagua I edited the question by posting another generic code. You can give suggestions in that.

Comment: @Slava Yes I got that class B has nothing to do with this but main calling a private method. I just posted the edited code showing what I want to do. If you have some suggestions on the structure that would be great

Comment: @Aconcagua Sorry, I don't know where that came from. Edited now

Comment: @varconst `protected: public:` – be aware that there's no nesting of scopes – it's just like a light switch, either it is on or off, just that you have three states in given case... Your new example now leaves out where `useunchangedvar` is called at all. Difficult to make any suggestions in respect to that function. As the getter now is gone, though, `A` being a friend of `B` would give it access to the protected member variable `a`.

Comment: @Aconcagua There is a public method in class A which calls usechangedvar

Comment: @Aconcagua Should I write "friend class A" inside class B? Would that give me "0" or "5" ? "5" being the value passed by user. I am worried that I will get "0" which is the default value of the protected variable

Comment: Yes, you declare A being friend of B inside B. Note this is not a mutual relation ship, i. e. if you want to be B a friend of A, too, you need to declare explicitly inside of A as well. When reading a variable you will get the value assigned the latest, i. e. while reading *before* assignment you get 0, *afterwards* you get 5. And be aware that if you create two instances of B, each one will have its own instance of `a` as well (`B b, bb; std::cout << bb.get() << b.get(); b.changevar(7); bb.changevar(8); std::cout << bb.get() << b.get();` prints 0087, assuming you re-enable `get` function).